# Boostrap form wizard messing'up with Javascript changes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to change input disabled and enabled or on select via Javascript and is working but when I switch tabs the changes is messing up,not showing, I don't know why, after switch tabs my select input doesn't show my values anymore.

HTML FORM UPDATED:

```
<div class="choice sectiuni btn-next" data-toggle="wizard-checkbox" rel="tooltip" id="solo" title="Solo">
    <input type="checkbox" id="solo" name="sectiuni" value="Solo">
   <h6>Solo</h6>
</div>

<div class="choice sectiuni btn-next" data-toggle="wizard-checkbox" rel="tooltip" id="duo" title="Duo/Trio/Quartet">
<input type="checkbox" id="duo" name="sectiuni" value="Duo/Trio/Quartet">
    <div class="icon">
    <img style="width: 48px;" src="assets/img/icons/duotrio.svg" />
    </div>
<h6>Duo/Trio/Quartet</h6>
</div>

<div class="choice sectiuni btn-next" data-toggle="wizard-checkbox" rel="tooltip" id="grupuri" title="Grupuri 5-12 dansatori">
  <input type="checkbox" id="grupuri" name="sectiuni" value="Grupuri">
<div class="icon">
<img style="width: 48px;" src="assets/img/icons/grupuri.png" />
</div>
<h6>Groups</h6>
</div>

<div class="choice sectiuni btn-next" data-toggle="wizard-checkbox" rel="tooltip" id="formatii" title="Formaţii peste 13 dansatori.">
  <input type="checkbox" id="formatii" name="sectiuni" value="Formatii">
<div class="icon">
<img style="width: 48px;" src="assets/img/icons/formatii.png" />
</div>
<h6>Formations</h6>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<select required name="category" class="form-control">
  <option id="alege" value="">Category</option>
  <option id="baby" value="4-6 ani - BABY">4-6 ani - BABY</option>
  <option id="mini" value="7-9 ani - MINI">7-9 ani - MINI</option>
  <option id="copii" value="10-12 ani - COPII">10-12 ani - COPII</option>
  <option id="juniori" value="13-15 ani - JUNIORI">13-15 ani - JUNIORI</option>
  <option id="seniori" value="+ 16 ANI - SENIORI">+ 16 ani - SENIORI</option>
  <option id="solo7" value="7 ani">Solo 7 ani</option>
  <option id="solo8" value="8 ani">Solo 8 ani</option>
  <option id="solo9" value="9 ani">Solo 9 ani</option>
  <option id="solo10" value="10 ani">Solo 10 ani</option>
  <option id="solo11" value="11 ani">Solo 11 ani</option>
  <option id="solo12" value="12 ani">Solo 12 ani</option>
</select>
</div>

<input required type="text" name="numecoregrafie" class="form-control" placeholder="Nume Coregrafie (*)">
<input required type="text" disabled name="numeformatie" id="numeformatie" class="form-control" placeholder="Nume Formatie (*)">
<input required type="text" name="coregraf" class="form-control" placeholder="Coregraf / Instructor (*)">
<input data-role="tagsinput" class="tagsinput" required type="text" name="dansator1" class="form-control" placeholder="dancer1,2,3">
<input required type="text" name="nrdansatori" class="form-control" placeholder="Numar Dansatori (*)">
```

JAVASCRIPT Code:

I think the problem is on JS code for the changes, but I don't have a clue why if I switch back a tab if I forgot something to complete the form is messing up.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#solo').on('click', function () {
        $('#baby,#mini,#copii,#juniori,#seniori').attr('style','display:none;');
    });  

    $('#duo').on('click', function () {
        $('#solo7,#solo8,#solo9,#solo10,#solo11,#solo12').attr('style','display:none;');
        $("input[type='text'][name='numeformatie']").removeAttr('disabled'); 
    });

    $('#grupuri').on('click', function () {
        $('#solo7,#solo8,#solo9,#solo10,#solo11,#solo12').attr('style','display:none;');
        $("input[type='text'][name='numeformatie']").removeAttr('disabled'); 
        $("input[type='text'][name='dansator1']").prop('disabled', true);
    });

    $('#formatii').on('click', function () {
        $('#solo7,#solo8,#solo9,#solo10,#solo11,#solo12').attr('style','display:none;');
        $("input[type='text'][name='numeformatie']").removeAttr('disabled'); 
        $("input[type='text'][name='dansator1']").prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

Comment: That's a lot of HTML to read through. Could you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please?

Comment: Done @DJDaveMark